# Wordpress RSS feed not work when custom filed have '&'

Tags: xml, wordpress, rss

WordPress RSS feed not work when custom filed have '&'. i think that may be XML error with character '&'.   How could I change to that & to '&amp' in custom field in wp-php code or any working way?
Error !!
I am using following code

```
function customFieldFilter($id) {
$meta = get_post_meta($id);
foreach ($meta as $key => $value) {
   update_post_meta($id, $key, esc_attr($value));
}
```

}
add_action('pre_post_update', 'customFieldFilter');

Comment: Your question needs significantly more detail. Please tell us exactly what you're trying to do; paste any code you're using and show us a screenshot or paste the error you're receiving.

Comment: In simple Question is : when custom field value contain character '&' entire RSS feed not working. when I add &amp instant of &. That is working. Is there any wp-function to character encode in custom fields? or any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're saving your custom field, try wrapping it in the `esc_html` WordPress function.

I'm not sure exactly how you save your custom fields, as you haven't provided any code, but for me this would be something along the lines of:

```
$habitat = esc_html( $_POST["habitat"] );
update_post_meta( $post->ID, "habitat", $_POST["habitat"] );
```

**However**, I would really like to see the way you're saving your custom fields as I believe that `esc_html` should be run by the `update_post_meta` function?

---

**EDIT**

Try adding this to your theme's `functions.php` (right at the bottom):

```
function custom_field_filter( $id ) {
    $meta = get_post_custom( $id );
    foreach ( $meta as $key => $value )
        update_post_meta( $id, $key, esc_html( $value ) );
}

add_action('pre_post_update', 'custom_field_filter', 100);
```

This is pure guess-work I'm afraid, I really can't find a lot of information on custom fields. This *should* retrieve all of the custom fields attached to the post, on save, and run them through a function to encode the `&` character to `&amp;` which will hopefully fix your RSS feed.

Comment: I am not use 'update_post_meta' function and not use code to save custom fields.I just made custom field after the post. In which file I have to update with  'esc_html' function? i mean how to set up it?

Comment: Sorry @miuranga I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to say. Could you please paste me the code you're using to create your custom field, or take a screenshot of your posting interface so that I can understand what kind of field you're referring to?

Comment: i am not creating custom fields by code. I use 'add new custom field' button in post. Could you pls tell me how to make custom fields with code?

Comment: Unless I'm wrong, I think that must be a plugin - I certainly have no such option when I'm creating a post in my WordPress installation. Do you have a custom field plugin installed?

Comment: sorry I ma not use any plug in for custom field. pls see image. I just want to update my custom fields by code.  - thanks

Comment: Thanks. That the think I am right look for. but unfortunately it doesn't work. :(  seems filter not work

Comment: Still not work. I have update esc_html() to esc_attr(). any potions?